# Azure storage export job fails with error code ResourceNotFound

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to export all blobs in a storage account to a set of hard disks, by creating an Import/Export job.  I created an export job, shipped four hard disks, and eventually - after several days - the job failed on the last disk. The "verbose" error log doesn't tell me very much:

```
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx0000 Time:2018-05-03T03:16:16.3261275Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

How can I avoid this error?  Is there any more information on *which* resource doesn't exist?

Thanks.

Alistair

Answer (score 0):

On how many disks have you successfully completed export job? Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-service?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) and this article will provide step-by-step instructions on using Azure Import/Export service to securely transfer large amounts of data to Azure Blob storage and Azure Files by shipping disk drives to an Azure data center. This service can also be used to transfer data from Azure storage to hard disk drives and ship to your on-premise sites. Data from a single internal SATA disk drive can be imported either to Azure Blob storage or Azure Files.

Comment: When a copy session fails, there are two options:

If the error is retryable, for example if the network share was offline for a short period and now is back online, you can resume the copy session. If the error is not retryable, for example if you specified the wrong source file directory in the command line parameters, you need to abort the copy session. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-tool-preparing-hard-drives-import-v1 for more information about resuming and aborting copy sessions.